# drupal_render does not render concatenated elements

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal and wonder if users who have experience in this kind of questions can help me with my issue.

The problem is that the output of `$complete0` through `drupal_render()` results in an empty space. Replacing `$complete0` with either `$title0` or `$name0` works just fine, however trying to render a concatenated field does not get the job done. Please see the piece of code below:

```
    try{
        $title0 = field_view_field('profile2', $user['recommendation'], 'field_rec0_title');
        $name0 = field_view_field('profile2', $user['recommendation'], 'field_rec0_title');
        $complete0 = "{$title0} {$name0}";
    }
    catch (EntityMalformedException $e) {}   
    if(empty($complete0)){
        $form['profile_evaluation']['field_field_eval_rec0']['und']['#title'] = 'Information missing';
    }
    else{
        $complete0['#title'] = 'Recommender 1';
        $form['profile_evaluation']['field_field_eval_rec0']['und']['#title'] = drupal_render($complete0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`drupal_render()` renders an array.

The var `$complete0` in your code is a string, so you shouldn't be passing it to `drupal_render()`.

Either use `render()`, which works for strings too, or convert `$complete0` to a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760).

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! Using 'render()' outputs a strange phrase: RrrayArray. I will give it a try and convert '$complete0' to a render array.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that - yes, printing an array (which is what's returned from field_view_field) will always yield the string _Array_. If you convert it to a render array you should have no problem here

Comment: I might be still missing a point of how do that.. Trying to replace '$complete0 = "{$title0} {$name0}"' with '$complete0 = array($title0, $name0)' results in the vertical output of each single element:
Given Name:
Alan
Title:
Prof.
However, what I would like to have should be printed on one line: Prof. Alan.